# How write down joint PMF, conditinals and marginals of Bernoulli and Binomial random variables?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I have the following problem, where I'd like to know whether I'm doing it right and whether the notation of the joint PMF is correct.

> One of two doctors, Dr. Hibbert and Dr. Nick, is called upon to perform a series of $n$ surgeries. Let $H$ be the indicator random variable for Dr. Hibbert performing the surgeries, and suppose that $E(H) = p$. Given that Dr. Hibbert is performing the surgeries, each surgery is successful with probability $a$, independently. Given that Dr. Nick is performing the surgeries, each surgery is successful with probability $b$, independently. Let $X$ be the number of successful surgeries.
>
> (a) Find the joint PMF of H and X.
>
> (b) Find the marginal PMF of X.
>
> (c) Find the conditional PMF of H given X = k.

a)
$$
P(X=x, H=h) = \left( \binom{n}{x} a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p \right)^{h} + 
\left( \binom{n}{x} b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p) \right)^{1-h}
$$

b) 
$$
P(X=x) = \sum_{h=0}^1 P(X=x, H=h) = \binom{n}{x} \left( a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p + b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p) \right)
$$

c)
$$
P(H=1|X=x) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1-p}{p} (\frac{b}{a})^x (\frac{1-b}{1-a})^{n-x}}
$$

Comment: What's r.v. indicator, and $I(h)$?

Comment: I edited it. r.v. = random variable, $I(h)$ is actually not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) should read:
$$
P(X=x, H=h) = \binom{n}{x} \left( a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p \right)^{h} \cdot
\left(b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p) \right)^{1-h}
$$

b) is correct:
$$
P(X=x) = \sum_{h=0}^1 P(X=x, H=h) = \binom{n}{x} \left( a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p + b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p) \right)
$$

c) should read:
$$
P(H=1|X=x) = \frac{a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p}{a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p +b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p)}$$
$$
P(H=0|X=x) = \frac{b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p)}{a^x(1-a)^{n-x} \cdot p +b^x(1-b)^{n-x} \cdot (1-p)}$$

Comment: The reason why @Did uses multiplication instead of addition is because if $h = 0$ in the expression using addition, the first term is $1$, not zero; and when $h = 1$, the second term is $1$, not zero, and you would get a probability exceeding $1$ in either case.

Comment: @heropup Thanks (although I would not say this is the *reason*, rather some post hoc confirmation).